# How do I enable snap-to-grid by default on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, icons, finder

I'm setting up a new Mac, and when I drag icons on my desktop (or in Windows, if I switch them to icon view), the icons don't snap into place unless I hold the command key down.

I can't recall how to make that "snap-to-grid" the default. And I can't find it in the Finder's View Options or Preferences.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

With the desktop active, under the *View* menu, choose *Show View Options* (or `cmd-J`) and select *Snap to Grid* in the *Arrange by* drop-down.

Still available under later versions of OS X, but now in the *Sort by* drop-down (still under *Show View Options*):

[image: "Snap to Grid" under OS X 10.8, Mountain Lion]

Comment: The picture saved me. The Swedish translation of this preference was so non-descriptive that I was staring at it without realizing what it was.

Answer (score 1):

Apple (command) + J, under View Options there is a drop down at the bottom "Arrange By:" select "Snap to Grid."

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the desktop, and click *Sort by* there should be a 'snap to grid' option

Answer (score 1):

For folders, open folder and right click to get popup menu

Select "show view options"

Select the "Sort by" combo box and there select "Snap to grid" as above.

Strange anyway that Apple hid this function so deep under "sort" behind already "show view options". IMHO snap to grid should be selectable all folders at once and be on at default...

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score 0):

You can over ride it using the command key if you cant find the option.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the Terminal commands:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Enable snap-to-grid for icons on the desktop and in other icon views.
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :DesktopViewSettings:IconViewSettings:arrangeBy grid" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :FK_StandardViewSettings:IconViewSettings:arrangeBy grid" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :StandardViewSettings:IconViewSettings:arrangeBy grid" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist

# Restart cfprefsd and Finder.
killall cfprefsd
killall Finder
```