# How do I find the Snap to Grid function on my new Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to find the Snap to Grid function on my new Mac.

I am following the instructions given in two answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/58102/48078) from another user, but there is no Snap to Grid option under "arrange by". What gives?

Comment: I hope I linked this question right, but you forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

As the answers said,

- press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> on the desktop, **or**
- right click it and select "Show View Options".

Then, in the window, select *Snap to Grid*.

[image]